# tf2onnx conversion of model with conv1d layers with group parameter set

Tags: tensorflow, onnx, onnxruntime, conv1d, tf2onnx

I tried to convert a tensorflow model containing conv1d layers with 'groups' parameter > 2, to onnx using tf2onnx. When I tried to read the onnx model us onnxruntime, I get the below error,

`This is an invalid model. In Node, ("sequential/conv1d/PartitionedCall", PartitionedCall, "", -1) : ("conv1d_input": tensor(float),"sequential/conv1d/ReadVariableOp:0": tensor(float),) -> ("sequential/conv1d/PartitionedCall:0",) , Error No Op registered for PartitionedCall with domain_version of 15`

The same conversion works when the 'groups' parameter is not set in the tensorflow conv1d layers.

I wonder if this is a compatibility issue with onnx.

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

As you can check [issue#1864](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx/issues/1864) is still open. So, the TensorFlow op `PartitionedCall` is unsupported for opset 15. Take a look at the troubleshooting page when you face the issue [tensorflow op is not supported](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx/blob/main/Troubleshooting.md#tensorflow-op-is-not-supported).

Now, at [line#46](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/19187d89b4e1cdf716269cf9142f805afae5541e/keras/layers/convolutional/conv1d.py#L46C13-L46C77) of Conv1D class in Keras it is mentioned that:

- Input channels and `filters` must both be divisible by `groups`.

So, just make sure this is not the problem here - as you mentioned:

> The same conversion works when the 'groups' parameter is not set in the tensorflow conv1d layers.

This means the `groups` parameter is then implicitly set to the default value `1` and therefore Input channels and `filters` are divisible by `groups`.

Finally, make sure to [use the largest opset compatible with your application](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/tutorials/tf-get-started.html#note-opset-number) and check the [ONNX opset support](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/reference/compatibility.html#onnx-opset-support) for compatibility which might be the actual culprit here as per your thought:

> I wonder if this is a compatibility issue with onnx.